# Exclude a directory from https redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, cloudflare, opencart2.x

I want to exclude "dir2" directory from my http to https redirect so I added the following htaccess directive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dir2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and then test it by visiting the following url:

http://example.com/dir2/ok.txt but I was redirected to https://example.com/dir2/ok.txt.

Website is using Opencart 2.x under php5.6, EncryptSSL and Cloudflare's DNS. Cloudflar's Crypto settings are as follows:

```
SSL: Full(Strict)
Always Use HTTPS: On
Automatic HTTPS Rewrites: On
```

Here is the full .htaccess: https://pastebin.com/U5k5wj4K

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add an htaccess rule. Because in this case, this is only for the exchange between the Cloudflare server and yours.

Add a Cloudflare rule from their control panel:
**Cloudflare -> Page Rules -> Create Page Rule**
And change the settings for your directory (not Always Use HTTPS and no Automatic HTTPS Rewrites)